# Update page content from live PHP and Python output using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, python, ajax

Long-time user, first-time asker. I've learned so much from the community and I love this site.

So here is what I'm shooting for. I want to have a web interface that runs ping commands on the backend. I ideally want a website that has a text input that allows you to enter an IP address or domain, a button that runs the command and a python script that runs from PHP to actually run the ping command. The tricky part for was to get the output to print to the website live as it is outputted on the command line. I want to do it this way as a way to future-proof the concept and eventually use different iperf parameters.

I built a little PHP page that "technically" gets the job done but I can't figure out how to only call the PHP script when the button is clicked. Since it's a PHP page, it runs whenever the page is loaded. So after some research, I figure ajax jquery is what I'm looking for. I've spent about 2 days trying different things that get me really close but it seems that I'm dancing around my solution.

From what I've learned about ajax, I essentially need a button that runs an ajax function that is linked to my working php script. I can get it to run the script but I can't get it to update the page content in a live/continuous manner. Only when the command is finished running.

Here is my php page that does what it needs to do but does it everytime the page is loaded/reloaded. Not ideal. I want the script to only run when the button is pressed.

liveping.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="liveping.php" id="ping" method="post" name="ping">
  Domain/IP Address: <input name="domain" type="text"> <input name="ping" type="submit" value="Ping">
 </form><?php

 if (isset($_POST['ping'])) {
   function liveExecuteCommand($cmd)
   {
       while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

       $proc = popen("$cmd 2>&1", 'r');

       $live_output     = "";
       $complete_output = "";

       while (!feof($proc))
       {
           $live_output     = fread($proc, 4096);
           $complete_output = $complete_output . $live_output;
           echo "<pre>$live_output</pre>";
           @ flush();
       }

       pclose($proc);
   }
 }

 $domain =  $_POST['domain'];

 $pingCmd = "python /var/www/html/ping.py ".$domain;

 if (isset($_POST['ping'])) {
   liveExecuteCommand($pingCmd);
 }

 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

ping.py:

```html
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi
import os
import sys
ping = "ping -c 5 -W 2 "+sys.argv[1]
os.system(ping)
```

---

Some things I've tried:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.onreadystatechange = setInterval(function() {
            if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
                document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        },100);
        function updateText() {
            ajax.open('GET', 'ajax.php');
            ajax.send();
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="updateText()">Click Me</button>
        <div id="content">Nothing here yet.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

OR

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      var auto_refresh = setInterval(
         function ()
         {
            $('#load_tweets').load('ajax.php').fadeIn("slow");
         }, 1000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
   </script>

  </head>

     <div id="load_tweets"> </div>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

WITH ajax.php

```html
<?php
while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

$proc = popen("ping -c 5 -W 2 google.com", 'r');

$live_output     = "";
$complete_output = "";

while (!feof($proc))
{
    $live_output     = fread($proc, 4096);
    $complete_output = $complete_output . $live_output;
    echo "<pre>$live_output</pre>";
    @ flush();
}

pclose($proc);
?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need python for showing ping results. Just two PHP files will be enough.

1. `index.php` will have the AJAX functionalities along with the form.
2. `ajax.php` will have the code to ping specified domain address.

I afraid that using jQuery you might not able to catch the live feed. Because it doesn't have any `onreadystatechange`. So, you might need to use vanilla JavaScript in this case. Here is a working demonstration:

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ping AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Domain/IP Address: <input id="domain" type="text"> 
        <input id="ping" type="button" value="Ping">
    </div>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script>
        function updateText(domain) {
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
              ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 3) {
                  var old_value = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML; 
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }               
            };          
            var url = 'ajax.php?domain='+domain;
            ajax.open('GET', url,true);
            ajax.send();
        }
        document.getElementById("ping").onclick = function(){
            domain = document.getElementById("domain").value;
            updateText(domain);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**ajax.php:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['domain'])) {
    function liveExecuteCommand($cmd)
    {
        while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

        $proc = popen($cmd, 'r');

        $live_output     = "";
        $complete_output = "";

        while (!feof($proc))
        {
            $live_output     = fread($proc, 4096);
            $complete_output = $complete_output . $live_output;
            echo "<pre>$live_output</pre>";
            @ flush();
        }

        pclose($proc);
    }   
    $domain =  $_GET['domain'];
    $pingCmd = "ping ".$domain;
    liveExecuteCommand($pingCmd);
}
else{
    echo "No post request";
}
?>
```

**Output:**

[image: Output_after_Executing]

**Declaimer:**

The ping command is changed as I am currently using Windows operating system. Update it according to your operating system.

As a first time questioner, you have described the problem neatly and also showed your efforts to solve the problem. I really appreciate it.

Comment: This solution worked for me! Thanks for the quick and thorough response! Also, I appreciate you pointing out my redundancy using a Python script. One less thing to deal with.

Comment: im testing this and i get all the result from the ping command on completion, at end of execution. is it possible to receive line by line response from ping command?

Comment: Works for me. Anyway to prevent multiple process running from clicking ping multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

```
ajax.readyState == 4
```

essentially means, script on the other side has finished ... 3 is partial.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState

Answer (score 1):

You just have to take all ajax script into the function

example:

```
function updateText() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET', // can be POST, too
          url: "ajax.php",
          crossDomain: true,
          data: {
                firstvar: firstvar,
                secondvar: secondvar
            },
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {

            if($.trim(data) == "false") {
                alert("Fail to recived data");
            }
            else {
                // Success getting data
                // Do some jobs
            }

          }
        });
    }
```

If you want to cancel submit to not refesh, U can use

```
return false; // At the end of the function above
```

Hope it helps.